# complex NSFetchRequest with groupBy

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I feel really stuck with this task, maybe somebody can suggest me a way to achieve this:

CoreData model

```
EKEvent <<---> EKCategory
```

`EKEvent` has properties: `NSDate *created;` and `NSNumber *amount;`

I need to fetch `EKEvent` objects with predicate like:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((created >= %@) AND (created <= %@))", self.fromDateFilterValue, self.toDateFilterValue];
```

and also it should be grouped by their categories (event has to-one relationship to category) cause I need to represent only categories in `UITableView` and show `event.@summ.amount` of fetched events for each category in `UITableViewCell`s.

the question is how do I construct my `NSFetchRequest` to get results which contains `NSDictionary` objects with:
1. `EKCategory` object (on maybe some field of this category, like `.title` and `.iconImageName`)
2. summ for all `.events` inside this category, confirm to passed `NSPredicate`
3. array of `EKEvent` objects confirmed to passed `NSPredicate`

Comment: So your table has a row for each category, and you want to show the sum of event amounts for each category (where the events are in a set date range)?

Comment: Yes, correct! I may not even need to fetch event objects itself, only category and events.@sum.amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment above: exactly.

Get the categories, fetching or however you want. Then, from each category, get the set of events from the relationship. Filter that set of events using your predicate. Then use the array KVC operator to get the sum of the remaining events.

Comment: Thanks! I did exactly how you tell me - it works fine. I spent a long of time to find some solution to complete this in a single NSFetchRequest or NSFetchedResultsController but looks like it was in vain, anyway the current solution has kind of a good performance